# Accessing Windows registry with PHP and DOTNET class

Tags: php, .net, windows, registry

This is a simple question: How do I access Windows' registry with PHP and the DOTNET class? What I want to do is to read a value that another program wrote.

Googling did not reveal much. I appreciate any answer!

Comment: You're going to use very different methods to access the registry in .Net vs PHP. Any reason you want to learn about both at this time?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, it works with the COM object:

```
$wscript = new COM('WScript.Shell');
$a = $wscript->RegRead('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\etc');
var_dump($a->value);
```