# How do I access the system registry in a PHP desktop / GTK application?

Tags: php, windows, registry, php-gtk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing Windows registry with PHP and DOTNET class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690297/accessing-windows-registry-with-php-and-dotnet-class)

Is there a way to access or insert a key in a client registry with PHP? I'm writing a GTK Internet based calc for my clients.

I don't see a way of accessing the registry with PHP. Is it possible and if so, how?

Comment: couple additional related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=registry+com+php+windows

Comment: The exact steps has been described in this document  https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/wiki/KnowledgeBase#How_do_I_read/write_to_Windows_Registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With normal PHP, not on the windows machine, probably the closest you could come is using something like [Javascript & XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Accessing_the_Windows_Registry_Using_XPCOM) to access the information you need and then provide it back to your php code with some form of AJAX control.

Since you're using php-gtk I'm not sure if the [win32std](http://pecl.php.net/package/win32std) package would help you as I'm not really experienced with php-gtk. You may also be able to use WScript.shell, [a rough example of which can be found here](http://php-gtk.eu/en/forum/topic/readwrite-registry-and-screen-class).